# How can I remove margins in HighCharts and avoid layout changes when removing data points?

Tags: highcharts

How can I remove margins in HighCharts.

Given this example:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
      type: "column",
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: "datetime",
        min: 1684324800000,
        max: 1684411200000,
        tickInterval: 3600000,
        labels: {
          formatter: (a) => {
            let d = new Date(a.value);
            return d.getUTCHours() 
          }
       }
    },
    yAxis: {visible:false},
    plotOptions: {
       series: {
         pointWidth: 1
       }
    },
    series: [
    {
        "name": "Vibration",
        "color": "blue",
        "data": [
            [
                1684383060000,
                2
            ],
            [
                1684401060000,
                1
            ]
        ]
    }
   ]
    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/36gqkocj/8/

I wish to remove the lead and trailing space.
[image]

I have tried lots of things setting startOnTick, endOnTick, marginLeft and marginRight, ...

The strange ting is that if you remove the last data point in the series, the layout suddenly changes into the wanted display:

[1684383060000, 2]

http://jsfiddle.net/xc0u7hm5/

Setting the margin to someting static is not an appealling option, as I will need to calculate the value dynamically.

Also it worries me that the display of the chart depends on the data being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference results from the fact that the default `pointRange` value is calculated in another way for multiple points.

From Highcharts API:

> **pointRange**: number, null
>
> The X axis range that each point is valid for. This determines the
> width of the column. On a categorized axis, the range will be 1 by
> default (one category unit). On linear and datetime axes, the range
> will be computed as the distance between the two closest data points.
>
> The default null means it is computed automatically, but this option
> can be used to override the automatic value.
>
> This option is set by default to 1 if data sorting is enabled.
> Defaults to null.

As a solution set `pointRange` to `1`:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      ...,
      pointRange: 1
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tysfuc53/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointRange

Comment: Nice, works like a charm!! Thank you. 
The documentation text is a bit cryptic imo, but it is a hard option to explain I guess